# How to set searchbar in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, searchbar

I am a new in react native i am try to set search bar in my application. To search in flatlist data. i am not able to search in flatlist data ,What is the error i don't know. how can i set how to resolve my problem please resolve my issue. i have attached the my code given below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, FlatList, View, TouchableOpacity, Image, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { dishesData } from './DishesData';
import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements'

const MenuListScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const state = {
    searchText: "",
    dishesData:[],
    filteredData: [],
  };
  let search = (searchText) => {
    this.setState({searchText: searchText});
  
    let filteredData = state.dishesData.filter(function (item) {
      return item.description.includes(searchText);
    });
  
    this.setState({filteredData: filteredData});
  };
  return (

    <View style={styles.container}>
      <SearchBar
        round={true}
        lightTheme={true}
        placeholder="Search..."
        autoCapitalize='none'
        autoCorrect={false}
        onChangeText={search}
        value={state.searchText}
      />

      <FlatList style={styles.list}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.listContainer}
        data={dishesData}
        horizontal={false}
        numColumns={1}
        keyExtractor={(item) => {
          return item.id;
        }}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('MenuDetail', { id: item.id })}
            >
              <Image
                style={styles.userImage}
                source={{ uri: item.imageSource }}
              />
              <View style={styles.cardFooter}>
                <View style={{ alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                  <Text style={styles.name}>{item.title}</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.position}>{item.price}</Text>
                  {/* <TouchableOpacity style={styles.followButton}
                    onPress={() =>
                      props.navigation.navigate('DetailsPage', item)
                    }>
                    <Text style={styles.followButtonText}>Buy Now</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity> */}
                </View>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          )
        }} />

    </View>

  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there you can filter items by using filter function and you are already doing that but for accuracy I'll suggest to do like this.

```
let search = (searchText) => {
    this.setState({searchText: searchText});
  
    let filteredData = state.dishesData.filter(function (item) {
      return item.description.toUpperCase().includes(searchText.toUpperCase());
    });
  
    this.setState({filteredData: filteredData});
  };
```

and to render the filtered items on `Flatlist` you have to toggle **data** array on FlatList

```
<FlatList style={styles.list}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.listContainer}
        data={state.searchText ? state.filteredData:state.dishesData}
        horizontal={false}
        numColumns={1}
        keyExtractor={(item) => {
          return item.id;
        }}.../>
```

Here is the Snack Link you can test as well [Working Example](https://snack.expo.dev/@zadu797/shallow-bubblegum)

Comment: ReferenceError: searchText is not defined .         This error

Comment: now try you are using class components and my code was functional level I changed it to class level

Comment: i don't know how to changed . because i am new in react native learning 2 weeks . please edit my code please

Comment: can anyone help me my problem.

Comment: I've added the snack link you can check it out

Comment: yes. you are adding components level but my code is deferents so i only asking you

Comment: your code is working but navigation issue. flatlist item click not working

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/@zadu797/shallow-bubblegum check this out

Comment: sorry, i am unable to understand. please edit my full code bro

Comment: bro please help me

Comment: please help still now not working